# MVC Html.LabelFor tooltip

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

Trying find out how to add a bit more space between the icon and the text

```
<td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.MiscellaneousSettings.StudentPhotoUrl, new { @class = "fa fa-question-circle", Title = "SomeTooltips" }) </td>
```

As you can see its really close:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your css:

```
label.fa:before {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Which will result in:

[image]

See [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/15xaqkLh/).

Answer (score 2):

Add a space before the student photo URL

```
<td>@Html.LabelFor(m => "&nbsp;" + m.MiscellaneousSettings.StudentPhotoUrl, new { @class = "fa fa-question-circle", Title = "SomeTooltips" }) </td>
```

Comment: Works perfect as well but the css route will work for all my icons - Thanks